# How can I define a pass through path in API gateway to point to a HTTP endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I am using `serverless` to deploy API gateway and lambdas. It works well for the paths whose targets are lambdas. But I'd like to define one path whose target is another HTTP endpoint, how can I do that?

When read this doc https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#pass-through-behavior, all it mentions is about targeting to lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

A) Create a Proxy Lambda function which does a [`301`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) redirect.

B) On an existing Lambda define a second path and do the `301` redirect directly in `serverless.yml` like this (taken from [here](https://forum.serverless.com/t/how-to-redirect-path-to-external-resource-aws/10353)):

```yaml
- http:
    path: /your-path/
    method: get
    integration: mock
    request:
      template:
        application/json: '{"statusCode": 301}'
    response:
      template: redirect
      headers:
        Location: "'your-redirect'"
      statusCodes:
        301:
          pattern: ''
```